# Oracle PL/SQL Just before root node query

Tags: oracle, plsql, hierarchical-data

Good morning,

So i have this situation : 
A table of data containing the dataID, parentdataID and some informations

```
MyTable
-Name
-WorkingPeriod
-ColorScheme
-ID
-parentID
```

To illustrate, the table works like this:

```
W0 (Always, Red)
--W1 (First time, red-blue)
----W2 (First step, red-blue-grey)
----W3 (Second step, red-blue-black)
------W4 (...)
--------W5 (...)
--W6 (Second time, red-green)
----W7 (First step, red-green-grey)
--W8 (Third time, red-pink)
```

I need, for each case, to get the closest node to root. Meaning that:

- for W3, W4 or W5, i want to get W1 informations (First time, red-blue)
- for W1, i want nothing (or it own information, can work with that)
- for W0, i want nothing.

Hoping i could make myself clear enough.
Have a good day.

Comment: Without sample data/tables to give a sample query on, may I suggest that you look at SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, and then parsing it to return null if null (W0), itself if only one node in path(W1), or default to second node (Root plus 1) for all other cases.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton I see what your idea is but i think it wouldn't work in my case. I added some details to my question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With full credit to Pablomatico for the start point, look at this expansion of his work that includes handling for IDs that are not 2-digits long, and re-joins to the source to bring back attributes of the just-before-root row:

```
WITH the_table AS (SELECT 'W0' item_id, NULL parent_id, 'Red' colour FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W1' item_id, 'W0' parent_id , 'blue' colour FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W2' item_id, 'W1' parent_id, 'Grey' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W3' item_id, 'W1' parent_id, 'Black' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W4' item_id, 'W3' parent_id, 'Mauve' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W5' item_id, 'W4' parent_id, 'Orange' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W6' item_id, 'W0' parent_id, 'Green' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W7' item_id, 'W6' parent_id, 'Grey' colour  FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W8' item_id, 'W0' parent_id, 'Pink' colour  FROM DUAL)
SELECT main_tab.item_id, main_tab.colour,main_tab.just_before_root, the_Table.colour
FROM                     
(SELECT item_id,
       colour,
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/') node_path, 
       CASE WHEN INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,2) = 0 THEN NULL
            WHEN INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,2) != 0
               AND INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,3) = 0 
               THEN SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),   INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,2)+1)
           ELSE SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'), INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,2)+1,INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,3) - INSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'),'/',1,2) - 1 ) END just_before_root
FROM the_table
CONNECT BY PRIOR item_id = parent_id
START WITH parent_id IS NULL) main_tab
left outer join the_table on  main_tab.just_before_root = the_table.item_id;
```

Returns:

```
ITEM_ID   COLOUR   JUST_BEFORE_ROOT    COLOUR_1   
"W0"      "Red"                           
"W1"      "blue"   "W1"                "blue"     
"W2"      "Grey"   "W1"                "blue"     
"W3"      "Black"  "W1"                "blue"     
"W4"      "Mauve"  "W1"                "blue"     
"W5"      "Orange" "W1"                "blue"     
"W6"      "Green"  "W6"                "Green"    
"W7"      "Grey"   "W6"                "Green"    
"W8"      "Pink"   "W8"                "Pink"
```

Comment: This is it ! This would work perfectly for me. Thank you and @Pablomatico for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can get it done with a hierarchical query. You could build the path of each node and extract the node just before the root from that string. Something like this might help you to get the final solution:

```
WITH the_table AS (SELECT 'W0' item_id, NULL parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W1' item_id, 'W0' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W2' item_id, 'W1' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W3' item_id, 'W1' parent_id_idrent FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W4' item_id, 'W3' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W5' item_id, 'W4' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W6' item_id, 'W0' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W7' item_id, 'W6' parent_id FROM DUAL
                   UNION
                   SELECT 'W8' item_id, 'W0' parent_id FROM DUAL)
SELECT item_id, 
       SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/') node_path, 
       SUBSTR(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(item_id, '/'), 5, 2) just_before_root
FROM the_table
CONNECT BY PRIOR item_id = parent_id
START WITH parent_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This base is good enough, and with the elements MichaelBroughton added, i am able to solve my problem. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace function getNodeCloserToRoot
(
  p_given_node varchar2(50);
)
return varchar2
is
 v_parent_node varchar2(50);
 v_current_node varchar2(50) := p_given_node;
begin
  select parentDataId 
     into v_parent_node
  from MyTable
  where dataId = v_current_node;
  loop
    exit when v_parent_node is null;
      v_current_node := v_parent_node;
      select parentDataId 
       into v_parent_node
      from MyTable
      where dataId = v_current_node;
  end loop;

  return v_current_node;
end;
```

Comment: This is a good idea too. Not a direct solution to my problem (but it is my bad, my question was not explicit enough i think). But i'll keep this, it can help me later. Thank you !